# Although this forum is about English language does it include questions about the latin and/or greek root words?

Tags: discussion

Although this forum is about English language does it include questions about the latin and/or greek root word questions?

Comment: What is meta and why is better there?

Comment: Meta is for questions about the site itself, for asking things like _"What is on-topic?"_, reporting bugs, or suggesting features.

Comment: Well, thats good to know for future reference, but are you able to answer the question in comments and then I an delete the question?  That sounds simpler.

Comment: The answer is sometimes, as it relates to a particular word of which you might want to know the etymology. Usually, though, it's not about Latin or Greek, words or roots in general.

Comment: @Jody: How would that help future people who have the same question as you?

Comment: I'm not a moderator of this site, simply a user who asks questions that I am curious about.  I have already had several exchanges with moderators who deemed questions "unworthy" or "off topic" and closed the question but the whole point for these sites are for people to ask questions.  Why ask, if your going to have your question removed or put on hold or moved to meta unknowingly until now?

Comment: I see no reason why not. If you're interested in Latin and Greek sources, check out my freshman etymology [class materials here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/wow/scans).

Comment: Interesting, but not the "J" I'm looking for.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Questions that ask for the etymology of an English word are acceptable, so long at you have done your research. [Etymonline.com](http://etymonline.com) is a good place to start and can tell you the basics of where many words come from, down to PIE roots.

If you still have questions after that then you should definitely ask here, stating how your research has thrown up questions.

So, you can't ask about Latin or Ancient Greek words specifically, but only how they pertain to English.